# Magento addColumn to Orders Grid with Options not displaying Values

Tags: php, magento

I have been searching the web for many hours now and soon running out of time, I have added a custom order attribute of `order_delivery_time` to `sales_flat_order`, `sales_flat_quote`, `sales_flat_order_grid` - the data is going in completely fine, so I know my issue does not lay there.

The issue is with adding the column to display the delivery times in the Orders Grid in the Magento backoffice when the column is to to `type => options`, when this is set to text the values appear and I can filter the results by typing them in. Ideally I want to be able to use a select field so the client can easily filter results and not get mixed results from typing 11.00 which sometimes returns 1.00

This is the code to add the column:

```
$this->addColumn('order_delivery_time', array(
    'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Delivery Time'),
    'index' => 'order_delivery_time',
    'type'  => 'options',
    'width' => '70px',
    'options'   =>  array(
        '11:00 AM' => '11:00 AM',
        '1:00 PM'  => '1:00 PM',
        '4:00 PM'  => '4:00 PM'
    )
));
```

(these values are always going to be the same, hence why they are put in this way).

So this is what the column looks like as the type set to text:
[image: Text Type Selected]

And then select:
[image: Select Type Selected]

I am really pulling my hair out as I simply cannot work out why it will not display the values when it's set to a select field instead of a text field.

Any help would be DEEPLY APPRECIATED.

Many Thanks,
Nathan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set array keys identical to **order_delivery_time** values in your collection.
Probably it should look something like this:

```
$this->addColumn('order_delivery_time', array(
    'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Delivery Time'),
    'index' => 'order_delivery_time',
    'type'  => 'options',
    'width' => '70px',
    'options'   =>  array(
        '11.00 AM' => '11:00 AM',
        '1.00 PM'  => '1:00 PM',
        '4.00 PM'  => '4:00 PM'
    )
));
```

Hope it helps, cheers!

Comment: OMG, Something as small as that always happens to me! What a twit. And yes.. that works perfectly now. Thanks!